# Draw a video to canvas firefox mobile

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm trying to draw a mp4 video to a canvas element as the video plays.

I'm using the code below, which works on most devices and browsers, but I realize on firefox mobile the mp4 video will play, but the canvas element won't. Is there any documentation or workarounds for this problem?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

canvas.width = 600; // set the canvas to be the size of the video
canvas.height = 338; 

function loop() {
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}loop();
```

I don't see any error codes, and all other javascript remains working. I tried shrinking the video down to a very small size to remove canvas size limitations but that didn't work either.

Comment: I also faced this issue, and I think it's a quite recent bug (± 3 months). But there is actually an NSErrorNotAvailable error thrown. I still didn't took the time to search for an existing bug report nor to create one if required though, and I didn't either found a workaround.

Comment: Really weird... we can draw videos that are being fed by a LocalMediaStream (i.e from getUserMedia, or canvas.captureStream), so I thought we could create a second video instance fed from the first's `captureStream` stream. But that doesn't work either... I will open an issue when I'll get time.